# Looking for email hosting

Tags: email, hosting

Am looking for email hosting for a small handful of domains ~ 5.

My requirements are pretty basic, maybe upto 3 inboxes per domain. Minimal storage required. Decent POP access with client and an option for SMTP.

Most of the providers I've sifted through in search results look pretty spammy.

Can anyone recommend a quality outfit at reasonable prices? UK, EU or US.

Comment: Unfortunately, these sorts of shopping-simplification questions are considered to be off-topic. Sure we can generate a list of not-too-shabby providers, but it would not be a good question/answer set for the ages.

Answer (score 1):

What about Google?  Yahoo?  Both will let you use your own domain for email, and Google (via Apps for your Domain) gives you a pretty complete branded experience.